# Python RTSP server for a webcams

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocols, webcam, rtsp

i need to build a rtsp server for the webcam using python3. Does anybody created and rtsp python server for web cams? Which libraries you used for rtsp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use any of existing services like [iSpy](https://www.ispyconnect.com/), [ZoneMinder](https://zoneminder.com/) or [Shinobi](https://shinobi.video/)?

If you want to stick with python, the [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) library can easily handle rtsp stuff. (But you need to explain a bit more, what you need to achieve) Here is a simple OpenCV snippet to view an rtsp stream:

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture("<rtsp stream link>")
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Comment: this is rstp client, not a server, isn't it?

Comment: Again, depends on what you need to do. I can fetch images/video, process them and do object recognition on them. If this is not the use case, maybe have a look at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/